# Is there a way to use Resque to dynamically load Ruby libraries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I have a Reporter worker for Resque in my Rails 3.2.8 application. I frequently add new reports for users, or fix bugs in existing reports.

Reports are deployed as Ruby modules whose methods are called by the Resque reporter worker.

Every time I deploy new code, I have to restart Resque. During that time, there are often one or more reports out there that are then killed, left with a status of "Running". What I want to find out is, is there a way to get Resque to reload the ruby modules that it uses to run the reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reloading you could stop the resque workers with a `kill -s QUIT`.  That will cause the workers to finish running their reports before shutting down.

More info on using signals with resque is here, https://github.com/defunkt/resque#signals.